# How to populate `ICollection<T>` property inside a `List<T>` linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, lambda

My Class

```
public partial class CTITLE_CHECKLIST : CError
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]
    public int ID_Tipo_Checklist { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public virtual CTipo_CheckList Tipo_CheckList { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST> Subtitulos { get; set; }
}
```

My method :

```
public List<CTITLE_CHECKLIST> GetCheked(string codigo, int tipoCheckList)
{
    try
    {

        var result = (from a in db.TITLE_CHECKLIST
                      from t in db.Tipo_CheckList
                      where a.ID_Tipo_Checklist == t.ID
                      where a.ID_Tipo_Checklist == tipoCheckList
                      select new CTITLE_CHECKLIST
                      {
                          Descripcion = a.Descripcion,
                          Id = a.Id,
                          ID_Tipo_Checklist = a.ID_Tipo_Checklist,
                          Tipo_CheckList = new CTipo_CheckList
                          {
                              Descripcion = t.Descripcion,
                              ID = t.ID,
                              ID_Depto = t.ID_Depto
                          },

                          Subtitulos = (from s in db.SUBTITLE_CHECKLIST
                                        where s.ID_Title == a.Id
                                        select new CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST
                                        {
                                            AmountCK = s.AmountCK,
                                            Descripcion = s.Descripcion,
                                            ID = s.ID,
                                            ID_Title = s.ID_Title,
                                            Numeracion = s.Numeracion,
                                            checkList = (from ck in db.CheckList
                                                         where ck.ID_Subtitle == s.ID
                                                         && ck.Codigo == codigo
                                                         select new CCheckList
                                                         {
                                                             CK = ck.CK,
                                                             Amount = ck.Amount,
                                                             Codigo = ck.Codigo,
                                                             Codigo_TFile = ck.Codigo_TFile,
                                                             Comentario = ck.Comentario,
                                                             ID = ck.ID,
                                                             ID_Subtitle = ck.ID_Subtitle,
                                                             UserCre = ck.UserCre,
                                                             UserMod = ck.UserMod
                                                         }).FirstOrDefault()


                                        })//here I put ToList
                      }).ToList();
```

An my error this :

> Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Linq.IQueryable<TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  `C:\Users\jmitchell\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TROP\TROP\Areas\TRAFICO\Controllers\LOGICA\CTITLE_CHECKLIST.cs`   136 49  TROP

And When I put .ToList, where say Here I put ToList it throw an error that say :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST] ToList[CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST]) ``' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

And I Know that if I change the property subtitles to `IEnumerable<T>` it will work, but, Im trying to bind this model from MVC4 post, And I doesn't bind with `IEnumerable<T>`, it bind with a `ICollection<T>`, `List<T>` , I am like 1 and a half day trying to figure out this problem.

Comment: You should really try to use more standard naming conventions; it'll make it easier for other developers to work with your code.

Comment: Also may consider doing something about that nesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

So the choices are not "do the whole thing in the database" or "do the whole thing in memory".  You want to do some of both.  Do everything on the DB end that you can, and then when you've done all of that, finish up the remaining operations in memory.  This general pattern (mostly leveraging `AsEnumerable`) will allow you to do this:

```
(from a in db.TITLE_CHECKLIST
from t in db.Tipo_CheckList
where a.ID_Tipo_Checklist == t.ID
where a.ID_Tipo_Checklist == tipoCheckList
select new //note were using an anonymous type here, 
           //as the real type can't take a non-list
{
    Descripcion = a.Descripcion,
    Id = a.Id,
    ID_Tipo_Checklist = a.ID_Tipo_Checklist,
    Tipo_CheckList = new CTipo_CheckList
    {
        Descripcion = t.Descripcion,
        ID = t.ID,
        ID_Depto = t.ID_Depto
    },

    Subtitulos = from s in db.SUBTITLE_CHECKLIST
                where s.ID_Title == a.Id
                select new CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST
                {
                    AmountCK = s.AmountCK,
                    Descripcion = s.Descripcion,
                    ID = s.ID,
                    ID_Title = s.ID_Title,
                    Numeracion = s.Numeracion,
                    checkList = (from ck in db.CheckList
                                where ck.ID_Subtitle == s.ID
                                && ck.Codigo == codigo
                                select new CCheckList
                                {
                                    CK = ck.CK,
                                    Amount = ck.Amount,
                                    Codigo = ck.Codigo,
                                    Codigo_TFile = ck.Codigo_TFile,
                                    Comentario = ck.Comentario,
                                    ID = ck.ID,
                                    ID_Subtitle = ck.ID_Subtitle,
                                    UserCre = ck.UserCre,
                                    UserMod = ck.UserMod
                                }).FirstOrDefault()
                }//note no ToList
})
//This will ensure that all operators that follow
//are done in memory, not on the DB end
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(checklist => new CTITLE_CHECKLIST
{
    Descripcion = checklist.Descripcion,
    Id = checklist.Id,
    ID_Tipo_Checklist = checklist.ID_Tipo_Checklist,
    Subtitulos = Subtitulos.ToList(),
});
```

Comment: I think its almost working, but It throw me an ArgumentNullException
Exception: 
Value cannot be null parameter name: source

Comment: @user2979690 Then figure out what is null, and what you need to do to prevent it from being null.

Comment: This Query return me just 1 element of type CTITLE_CHECKLIST, and inside it have a Non public member, some help please. I trying to do the imposible to solve this problem.

Comment: @user2979690 There really isn't enough information to look into more fundamental problems with your query not providing the information you want it to.

Comment: @user2979690 That's not what the code in the answer I provided does.  It generates an anonymous type in the intermediate result set, but then projects that into the actual type that you have in a subsequent `Select`.

Comment: The final type of my result using this query is : {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<<>f__AnonymousType2<string,int,int,TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CTipo_CheckList,System.Linq.IQueryable<TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST>>,TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CTITLE_CHECKLIST>}, Im having bad days with this query.

Comment: @user2979690 I then repeat my previous comment.  If you're using my code, that won't be the case.

Comment: Yes, but at the end the type CTITLE_CHECKLIST, have to return many items not 1 item, I'm trying to figureout how to solve this, But I cant, I really have the code that fill it, but in a type Ienumerable, and I need it in a List or ICollection, MY models : CTITLE_CHECKLIST is a list, and inside have CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST that its a list too

Comment: @user2979690 Yep, and in my answer I showed you exactly how to create a `List<CTITLE_CHECKLIST>` that has a property of type `List<CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST>`.  That's exactly what this query resolves to.  To get the results you're getting you must have changed the query in some way.

Comment: Hey I copy your code exactly using copy and paste, and it return me a annonimous type, I have like 3 days with this problem, I really want it to work... Im not lying

Comment: @user2979690 The code that I provided has a projection to `CTITLE_CHECKLIST`.  it will not result in a query of anonymous types.  You must have not copied it properly.

Comment: I really know how to copy and paste, Im not modifying your code, And always return me this type : {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<<>f__AnonymousType2<string,int,int,TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CTipo_CheckList,System.Linq.IQueryable<TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CSUBTITLE_CHECKLIST>>,TROP.Areas.TRAFICO.Controllers.LOGICA.CTITLE_CHECKLIST>},

But, Thanks for your help, I'll keep trying, with diferent things.